# MVC: you leave - I stop or: you leave - I don't care?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A user uploads an excel sheet, this triggers a process that might take some time: the sheet is saved (quick) and then processed (takes a while and is independet of communication with the client). After that, a view is returned.

**What happens if the user uploads the file and closes the browser immediatly. Will the triggered process continue until it finds that it has no one to return the view to?**

I guess once the process is triggered, the server does not know/care if the client still is active until for the next time that the server communicates with the client, and so the server will continue the work. But I am not sure.. and thank you for your input on this newbie question!

Comment: Without wanting to give you too much of a hard time - this seems like a very easy thing to try...

Comment: The question is: do _you_ care? Do you want to know the processing is still busy, or has finished or failed? If so, perhaps a separate service for document processing is advisable, contrary to fire-and-forget-and-we'll-see-what-happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process will continue, even if the client refresh and upload a new file (the old request is still running). Be careful, it can be a source of conflict !

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a different question to ask, as opposed to an answer, but what do you do if the user gets tired waiting for a very slow response and starts hammering refresh, thus resubmitting, for example?

Generally, a good way to deal with this would be to spin off the slow process to run async, and return to the client, who can then poll for progress.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to try by yourself.

But as HTTP is stateless there is no way for the web server to safely detect that the browser has been closed.

But if you really want to detect that the browser remains open you can either use web sockets or long polling requests while the actual processing is made.